# $scope is not updated after ngResource POSTed new item successfully

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, ngresource

I have run into this issue in my app several times. I have a fun ngResource resources that I attach to `$scope` as `$scope.jogasok = Jogas.query();`, and I create a new resource in the same scope by calling something like

```
$scope.addJogas = function (jogas) {
      $scope.isDisabled = true;
      var j = new Jogas(jogas);
      j.$save(function (value) {
        $scope.isDisabled = false;
      }, httpErrorHandler);
    };
```

where `Jogas` is an ngResource

```
.factory('Jogas', function ($resource) {
    var Jogas = $resource('/jogasok/:id/:action', {
      'id': '@_id',
      'action': '@action'
    }, {
      'ujBerlet': {'method': 'POST', 'params': {'action': 'ujberlet'}}
    });
    return Jogas;
  })
```

The POST call is successful, thus reloading the page shows the new item in `$scope.jogasok`, but the new item is not shown if I don't reload.

Have can I get `$scope.jogasok` reloaded/extended automatically when `$save` has finished?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out my own dumbness concerning this question.

`$scope.jogasok` is an `Array`, thus its value will not change without changing it.

The most basic solution is to reload `$scope.jogasok` in the success handler:

```
$scope.addJogas = function (jogas) {
  $scope.isDisabled = true;
  var j = new Jogas(jogas);
  j.$save(function (value) {
    $scope.jogasok = Jogas.query();
    $scope.isDisabled = false;
  }, httpErrorHandler);
};
```